# Facebook "Like" Button (box style) increases width in divider layout?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like, fbml, conflict

I've installed a Facebook "Like" box-style button in one of my websites.
Functionality-wise, everything seems to be working fine.  Until I check the layout.

Facebook seems to increase the width of my wrapping divider, which already has a set fixed width.

The current layout is based off of dividers, and the whole 100% height + centered body and footer set.  I know it's because of Facebook's script, because the layout's perfect when I visit every other page that does not have the Facebook Like button installed.

Is there some sort of workaround for this?

The Facebook script I'm using is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=XXXX&amp;xfbml=1"></script> 
<fb:like href="" send="false" layout="box_count" width="60" show_faces="false" action="like" font=""></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out!  After much googling though.
The problem is the first line of the script needs to be the FIRST CHILD of the BODY tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Reference: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=45600